# How to deserialize nested JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I know this type of question has probably been asked before, but I when I tried it it didn't quite work. I am new to working with jsons in C#. So I have a JSON file (example from the file is shorter than in real one), from which I want to get values. Values I need are in 'languages' array.

There is a great solution from getting data from the array on the website:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm

But, I have a problem because there is a 'Result' attribute, and I don't know how to go through it. Also there are a lot of attributes in the top of the json ('Headers') Which I don't need but i think I still need to include them in my code?. It would really help if someone could please send me some tips or a solution on how to do it. There will also be an incomplete example of code, which gives errors. Also if any one of you could also reply with maybe a good video on YouTube or website about Json.net except from the official documentation, that would be amazing.   Thanks

Json:

```json
{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Headers": {
    "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'none'",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;",
    "x-dp-watson-tran-id": "0cf1366a-5bd0-4210-a291-93a30ea0ac62",
    "X-Request-ID": "0cf1366a-5bd0-4210-a291-93a30ea0ac62",
    "x-global-transaction-id": "0cf1366a-5bd0-4210-a291-93a30ea0ac62",
    "Server": "watson-gateway",
    "X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT": "5",
    "X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency": "92",
    "Date": "Wed, 25 Aug 2021 13:21:23 GMT",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
  },
  "Result": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "language": "af",
        "language_name": "Afrikaans",
        "native_language_name": "Afrikaans",
        "country_code": "ZA",
        "words_separated": true,
        "direction": "left_to_right",
        "supported_as_source": false,
        "supported_as_target": false,
        "identifiable": true
      },
      {
        "language": "ar",
        "language_name": "Arabic",
        "native_language_name": "العربية",
        "country_code": "AR",
        "words_separated": true,
        "direction": "right_to_left",
        "supported_as_source": true,
        "supported_as_target": true,
        "identifiable": true
      },
      {
        "language": "az",
        "language_name": "Azerbaijani",
        "native_language_name": "آذربایجان دیلی",
        "country_code": "AZ",
        "words_separated": true,
        "direction": "right_to_left",
        "supported_as_source": false,
        "supported_as_target": false,
        "identifiable": true
      }
    ]
}
```

My **incomplete** code:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace WorkingWithFiles
{
    class FullJson
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<Headers>> Headers { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<Languages>> Result { get; set; }

    }

    class Headers
    {
        public string xXssProtection { get; set; }
        public string xContentTypeOptions { get; set; }
        public string contentTypeOptions { get; set; }
        public string cacheControl { get; set; }
        public string pragma { get; set; }
        public string strictTransportSecurity { get; set; }
        public string xDpWatsonTranId { get; set; }
        public string xRequestId { get; set; }
        public string xGlobalTransactionId { get; set; }
        public string server { get; set; }
        public string xEdgeConnectMidMileRTT { get; set; }
        public string xEdgeConnectOriginMEXLatency { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string connection { get; set; }
    }

    class Languages
    {

    }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string path = root + @"\SubtitleTranslator\LanguagesList.json";

            FullJson fullJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FullJson>(File.ReadAllText(path));
            Console.WriteLine("Status code: " + fullJson.StatusCode);





        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing and retrieving a raw response instead of just the data?

Comment: Like, i said I am completely new to working with Json in c# so I really don't know how to get to it. Or how to do it

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the languages array? You simply access it via `fullJson.Result.Languages`, with result not being a dictionary, but rather a list of Language objects.

Comment: Within your JSON, `Result` is simply the key of a key value pair, so it's effectively a dictionary in C#. It turns out that `Result` simply has one attribute, languages, which itself is a List of objects. Thus, you could model `Result` as a `Dictionary<string, List<Languages>>`

Comment: @DavidL What I am trying to do is, Compare different languages for supported_as_target and supported_as_source. So when a users sends in a Source language and a Target Language. Program checks if Languages are compatible.

Comment: @DavidL - that does not look like a raw response - the HTML headers have been  packaged as JSon.

Comment: @DjAmadej - what is your .net version?  Because Newtonsoft is outmoded. Might still be a good choice, but `System.Text.Json` is the future.

Comment: if you're unsure how you would write some big json objects, then just try to use some of online generators [like this one](https://app.quicktype.io/) it's way easier to learn out of example instead of writing everything blindly (at least for the first time)

Comment: @HenkHolterman newtonsoft.json is outmoded...? Hmm.. checked nuget stats recently? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All code was tested using VS2019 and working properly.

The simpliest way will be

```
var root =Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var path = root + @"\SubtitleTranslator\LanguagesList.json";
 var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
List<Language> languages = null;
if( jsonDeserialized.StatusCode== 200) languages=jsonDeserialized.Result.languages;
```

or if you don't need any data except languages, try this code

```
var languages= JObject.Parse(json)["Result"]["languages"].ToObject<Language[]>();
```

in this case you will need only Language class

OUTPUT (in both cases)

```
[{"language":"af","language_name":"Afrikaans","native_language_name":"Afrikaans","country_code":"ZA","words_separated":true,"direction":"left_to_right","supported_as_source":false,"supported_as_target":false,"identifiable":true},
{"language":"ar","language_name":"Arabic","native_language_name":"العربية","country_code":"AR","words_separated":true,"direction":"right_to_left","supported_as_source":true,"supported_as_target":true,"identifiable":true},
{"language":"az","language_name":"Azerbaijani","native_language_name":"آذربایجان دیلی","country_code":"AZ","words_separated":true,"direction":"right_to_left","supported_as_source":false,"supported_as_target":false,"identifiable":true}]
```

Update

you can test it using Console.WriteLine

```
foreach (var lg in languages)
{
Console.WriteLine($"Language Name: {lg.native_language_name}, Coutry Code: {lg.country_code}");
        
}
```

Language class

```
public class Language
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string language_name { get; set; }
    public string native_language_name { get; set; }
    public string country_code { get; set; }
    public bool words_separated { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; }
    public bool supported_as_source { get; set; }
    public bool supported_as_target { get; set; }
    public bool identifiable { get; set; }
}
```

another classes (if needed)

`````
public class Root
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public Headers Headers { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
public class Headers
{
    [JsonProperty("X-XSS-Protection")]
    public string XXSSProtection { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X-Content-Type-Options")]
    public string XContentTypeOptions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Content-Security-Policy")]
    public string ContentSecurityPolicy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Cache-Control")]
    public string CacheControl { get; set; }
    public string Pragma { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Strict-Transport-Security")]
    public string StrictTransportSecurity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("x-dp-watson-tran-id")]
    public string XDpWatsonTranId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X-Request-ID")]
    public string XRequestID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("x-global-transaction-id")]
    public string XGlobalTransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT")]
    public string XEdgeConnectMidMileRTT { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency")]
    public string XEdgeConnectOriginMEXLatency { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Connection { get; set; }
}


public class Result
{
    public List<Language> languages { get; set; }
}
````
`````

Comment: I tried it but got this as response when I tried to do Console.WriteLine(langs): System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WorkingWithFiles.Language]

Comment: @DjAmadej See my update how to use write line.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the contents of the `languages` array, then use Json.NET's [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) feature:

```
class LangInfo {
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string language_name { get; set; }
    public string native_language_name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

```
var langs = JObject.Parse(json)["Result"]["languages"].Children()
    .Select(token => token.ToObject<LangInfo>()).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it didn't work I tried it, and got that error: Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert[T,U](T token)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert[T,U](IEnumerable`1 source)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at WorkingWithFiles.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: My bad, I fixed it.